# Iterate through Firebase ref to load its children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to individually load each child of an object from firebase.

A nonworking snippet of code to better explain the idea is given below:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firebase.database().ref('/users/'+userId+"/foo/list").once('value').then(function(list) {
    var reffoo = firebase.database().ref().child("/foo/");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      ref = reffoo.child(list[i]);
      $scope.foo[ref] = $firebaseObject(ref);
    }
  });
```

As per my analysis the issue is, *$firebaseObject makes async call to firebase* but don't know how to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to obtain a `ref` to your collection and iterate over using 
[`data snapshot` api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)  i.e.,

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+userId+"/foo/list");

ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    $scope.foo[childKey] = childData;
  });
});
```

If you want to maintain actual `angularFire` reference to an object then [`$firebaseArray`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasearray) comes to help:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);

// add an item
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(...);

// remove an item
list.$remove(2).then(...);

// make the list available in the DOM
$scope.list = list;
```